# Trouble using projector with tablet via USB

Tags: windows-8, tablet, projector

I have a Sanyo PRO-x multiverse projector, model number PLC-SW30.  I am trying to use it with a Windows 8 tablet (Dell XPS 12).  The tablet does not have any video ports.  So, I am trying to connect to the projector via a USB connection.  It is not noticing the projector at all.  Can I send video to the projector via USB?  Or is that USB port used for something else.

Looking at device manager, I can see an Unknown device listed.  Searching the web, I have not been able to find any drivers for this projector.

Can anybody tell me where I can find drivers for this projector and how I can get it to work with the tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use the USB port on that projector for video.  It's for passing commands from the projector's (remote) buttons back to the computer.

According to [the manual](http://office.manualsonline.com/manuals/mfg/sanyo/plcsw30_1.html?p=10) (page 10):

> Connect the USB port of your computer to this port when you wish to use the PAGE ed buttons on the
>   remote control to scroll back and forth pages on the screen of the connected computer.

As for drivers for that projector, that'll probably be tough since it's old, and [Sanyo was bought by Panasonic in 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanyo#Acquisition).  Looking around on Panasonic's site for drivers I find nothing for those older Sanyo projectors.

Perhaps grab yourself a [DisplayLink USB video adapter](http://www.displaylink.com/shop/adapters) and try that.  If you hook up video that way then you only need drivers for the DisplayLink adapter, which are easily available (Windows 8 even has included drivers for them I believe).